# How to get the table names from "SQL script" in SQL Server database

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to get the list of all tables used in a SQL script, using TSQL

For Example

SQL Script:

```
SELECT t1.Name, t2.Age
FROM TableOne t1 LEFT JOIN
     TableTwo t2
     ON T1.Number=T2.Number
```

expected Output:

```
TableOne
TableTwo
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Put it into a stored proc then use `sys.dm_sql_referenced_entities` on the proc.

Comment: If it is just a single query, you can also use a view or use `sys.sql_expression_dependencies`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just idea and not fully-baked solution.

You could use execution plan to get object names:

```
-- in the same session
SELECT t1.Name, t2.Age
FROM TableOne t1 LEFT JOIN
     TableTwo t2
     ON T1.Number=T2.Number

;WITH XMLNAMESPACES('http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2004/07/showplan' 
                     AS ns)
,cte AS (
    SELECT t.text, p.query_plan
    FROM sys.dm_exec_requests AS r
    CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(plan_handle) t
    CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_query_plan(plan_handle) p
    WHERE r.session_id = @@SPID
), val AS (
    SELECT DISTINCT s.c.value('@Schema', 'SYSNAME')  AS [schema],
                     s.c.value('@Table', 'SYSNAME')  AS [table_name]
    FROM cte c
    CROSS APPLY c.query_plan.nodes('//ns:Object') AS s(c)
)
SELECT *
FROM val
WHERE [schema] IS NOT NULL;
```

Be aware that it could return dependent objects(for example when view/table function is used).

Answer (score 0):

All,

Thank you for your recommendations.

Unfortunately I cannot use execution plans as these scripts are saved in a table. 
Also I cannot create stored procedures on top of these scripts as we have 300+ scripts.
However I have started with below scripts where it is helping me to get the tables so far. but there are few scenario (like Sub query) where I am still working. 
Thanks again

```html
WHILE (@i<=25)
BEGIN
SELECT @SQLScript=SQLQuery 
  ,@TargetTableName=TargetTableName
  ,@TargetDB=TargetDB 
  FROM #T WHERE Number=@i

  SELECT @MaxLen=LEN(@SQLScript) 

 IF EXISTS (SELECT  1 FROM #T WHERE  @SQLScript LIKE '%JOIN%')
 BEGIN
  
  SELECT @TargetTableName AS TargetTableName
    ,SUBSTRING(@SQLScript,CHARINDEX('FROM',@SQLScript)+5 ,CHARINDEX(' ',SUBSTRING(@SQLScript,CHARINDEX('FROM',@SQLScript)+5,@MaxLen))) AS TableUsed
  UNION

  SELECT @TargetTableName AS TargetTableName
    ,SUBSTRING(@SQLScript,CHARINDEX('JOIN ',@SQLScript)+5,CHARINDEX(' ',SUBSTRING(@SQLScript,CHARINDEX('JOIN ',@SQLScript)+5,@MaxLen))

  )
  END
 IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM #T WHERE CHARINDEX(' ',SUBSTRING(@SQLScript,CHARINDEX('FROM',@SQLScript)+5,@MaxLen))=0)-- Applies where there is SQLquery ends with single table
 BEGIN


 SELECT   @TargetTableName AS TargetTableName,SUBSTRING(@SQLScript,CHARINDEX('FROM',@SQLScript)+5,@MaxLen)
  --EXECUTE sp_executesql @SQLScript
  
 END
 SET @i=@i+1
END
```